# How to apply Butterworth High Pass Filter

Tags: signal-analysis, python, highpass-filter

I have a problem with applying Butterworth High Pass Filter to my data. I would like to print filter for `Bx` and `By` matrix. As you can see I have both positive and negative values,

> how to apply `math.fabs()` to `Bx` and `By` to get only positive
>   values?

For my high pass filter I have those requirements:

Fc = 2 Hz

I would like to cut off values below 100 pT.

A part of my current code is:

```
plt.ylabel('Pico Tesle [pT]')
plt.xlabel('Time [ms]')
plt.grid()
plt.plot(time[51:-14], Bx[51:-14], label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.1, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(time2[1:-14], By[1:-14], label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.1, linestyle="-")
plt.legend(loc='upper right', frameon=False, )
```

And a chart:

[image]

UPDATE:
I have used this function to generate absolute values for Bx and By matrix.

```
plt.subplot(413)
np.absolute(fft1)
plt.plot(time[51:-14], np.absolute(fft1), color='r', linewidth=0.1, linestyle='-')
plt.grid()

plt.subplot(414)
np.absolute(fft2)
plt.plot(time2[1:-14], np.absolute(fft2), color='b', linewidth=0.1, linestyle='-')
plt.grid()
```

What I received thanks to that is that all my measurements (here are atmospheric discharges) are only in positive values (pT - picoTesla). First plot shows Canal 1, second plot shows Canal 3, and the third plot shows both Canals (Channels) combined.

[image]

No, I need (I guess) use High Pass Filter to cut off all measurements below 100 pT. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm confused. A high pass filter has nothing to do with cutting off low values. On the contrary, all the filter types you normally encounter are *linear* systems, and cutting something off is pretty much the opposite of linear behavior. So, I think you are confusing things.

Comment: You must be right, I am new to signal processing so I probably wrote something incorrect. So maybe you have idea how to cut off all the data below 100 pT, and leave only those above that value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code answers my question completely.

```
fig2 = plt.figure(2)
plt.title('Butterworth High Pass Filter')
Sampling = float(266336)/300
HalfSampling = float(Sampling)/2
Wn = float(1)/HalfSampling
b, a = signal.butter(3, Wn, 'high')
BxHPF = signal.filtfilt(b, a, Bxfft)
ByHPF = signal.filtfilt(b, a, Byfft)
plt.plot(BxTime, BxHPF, label='Canal 1', color='r', linewidth=0.5, linestyle="-")
plt.plot(ByTime, ByHPF, label='Canal 3', color='b', linewidth=0.5, linestyle="-")
```

Comment: I know, but I've got information that I have to wait 2 hours to do so.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do thresholding, then you don't have to use any filter. Just throw away all those samples whose values are below your threshold (in this case, $100 \ \mathrm{pT}$).

In MATLAB, you could do something like this:

```
data(data < 100) = [];
```

If you want to keep the array size, then you might consider replacing those values with `NaN` or `0` instead of `[]`.

Comment: I guest it will work, do you know how this operate in python?

Comment: It would be pretty similar. You can do `data[(data < 100)] = 0` to replace those values by 0 or `data = data[(data >= 100)]` to delete them.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I used this formula and it is working.
`np.clip(np.absolute(fft1),100,1000)`